# Bluetooth comport programming very slow

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port

this is Dharmesh i developed one application of gps. my gps connected via Bluetooth but my program take too much time identify comport. but if i connected my gps with usb cable it run easily any one face this issue and how to overcome this issue.

thanking you......

Answer (score 0):

This may be a side effect of the fact that you let the bluetooth port go between attempts. Bluetooth connections setup and teardown are very expensive, so if you connect to the GPS, you should remain connected. Of course, that doesn't help during dev, so once you know the bluetooth connection works, it probably makes sense to use the USB cable except when testing the connection for regressions.